# ¿Como puedo hacer INNER JOIN entre una tabla en SQL SERVER y un SP de un servidor vinculado?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, linkedserver

Tengo una base de datos en un servidor llamada DataMart y otra en otro servidor llamada companyTalent. Logré realizar la conexión correctamente y ya logré ejecutar una consulta SELECT de un servidor al otro de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    t1.campo1
    ,...
FROM
    [LinkedServer].[BaseDatosRemota].[esquema2].[TablaRemota] t1
```

Pero ahora quiero realizar un `inner join` de mi tabla local con el resultado de mi procedimiento almacenado del otro servidor el cual para llamarlo quedaria asi:

```
exec [LinkedServer].[BaseDatosRemota].[esquema].[NombreProcedimiento]
             @DateStart ='2023-03-01',
             @DateEnd= '2023-04-14', 
             @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
             @EmpData = @EmpData_Dummy
```

¿Como puedo hacer un inner join del resultado de mi procedimiento almacenado anterior con una tabla?

Sé que debo realizar un procedimiento almacenado para ingresar los parámetros para el SP que está en el otro servidor, pero no sé como puedo relacionar ese SP con una tabla.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede hacer un join directamente entre una tabla y el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado, aún este estuviera en la misma base de datos.

La alternativa que generalmente se usa es la de almacenar los resultados del procedimiento almacenado en una tabla (puede ser temporal) y hacer el *join* con dicha tabla.

Dicha tabla debe tener la misma estructura del conjunto de datos devuelto por el procedimiento.

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temporal (
    Campo1 int, 
    Campo2 varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO #Temporal
EXEC [LinkedServer].[BaseDatosRemota].[esquema].[NombreProcedimiento]
         @DateStart ='2023-03-01',
         @DateEnd= '2023-04-14', 
         @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
         @EmpData = @EmpData_Dummy;

SELECT miTabla.Campo1, miTabla.Campo3, t.Campo2
  FROM miTabla
       inner join #Temporal t ON t.Campo1 = miTabla.Campo1
```

Comment: Excelente, esto era lo que buscaba solo que no se me ocurrio realizar esta opcion